# Connecting a HomePlug over CoAx

Tags: powerline-networking, coaxial

Short questions: Can I connect two HomePlugs through a Coaxial cable? Will it yield the same throughput as through standard single phase wires?

Longer version: I need a GbE connection between 2nd and ground floor. The needed outlets are almost in a direct vertical line. I have a direct CoAx running from 2nd to the ground floor following almost the exact path (originally meant for a TV antenna). Power lines between the two goes through, I'm guessing, through at least 2 breakers (possibly 3).

I've looked at (but not invested in) the following options.

1. Wireless AC networking
2. GbE HomePlug (such as Tenda P1000M)
3. MoCA 2.0 stuff from ActionTec

So #1 and 3 are expensive. And I'm not confident #1 will get good throughput as I'd have to do multiple repeaters. #2 is the cheapest option, however, again the throughput may suffer due to multiple breakers.

So, I was wondering whether I could wire the coax to standard wall sockets (copper shield as neutral and the core as live) and connect them via the homeplugs.

Would this work? Any pitfalls that I'm not seeing?

Comment: If you're going to wire anything to coax you might as well wire wireless AC since that already designed to use coax connectors anyway. That said I've never seen anyone report more than 200Mbps throughput on Homeplugs of any sort.

Comment: I guess you are referring to something like ActionTec's WCB6200Q which I cannot find on Amazon. What's there is WCB3000N which is not MoCA 2 :(

Comment: No, I mean any router with an external antenna connector

Comment: Hmm... I'm not familiar with that technique and my googling didn't turn up anything either. Do you have a link to anything related to this?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wifi+coax

Comment: @qasdfdsaq That's a pretty neat trick. I'll look up it's speeds...

Answer (score 2):

I think the big pitfall you weren't seeing is this: How were you planning on providing electrical power to the HomePlug AV2 adapters while at the same time guaranteeing that you don't end up short-circuiting your home's electrical wiring with this coax cable?

Even if you did the electrical engineering work to allow the RF signals to travel the coax without 120VAC going along with it, you might not get the speed you want with just a single coax. Some HomePlug AV2 equipment gets its high data rates by employing MIMO, which requires 3-wire (grounded) outlets. A coax cable only has 2 conductors, so you wouldn't be able to do MIMO.